# Наложение водяного знака в центр изображения

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.
Есть функция наложения водяного знака на загружаемое фото:

```
function watermark($file, $watermark)
{

if (empty($file) || empty($watermark)) {
    return false;
}

$wh = getimagesize($watermark);
$fh = getimagesize($file);
$rwatermark = imagecreatefrompng($watermark);
$rfile = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);

imagecopy($rfile, $rwatermark, $fh[0] - $wh[0], $fh[1] - $wh[1], 0, 0, $wh[1], $wh[1]);
imagejpeg($rfile, $file, '80');
imagedestroy($rwatermark);
imagedestroy($rfile);

return true;

}
```

Код загрузки фото:

```
foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $k => $f) {

if (!$_FILES['file']['error'][$k]) {
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k])) {
    $newfile = "$imgDir/" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$k];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k], $newfile)) {

    watermark($newfile, './water.png');

    $fsave = $_FILES['file']['name'][$k];

    header("Location: /index.php");


        }
    }
}
}
```

Так вот, водяной знак сейчас ложится в правый нижний угол.
Каким образом сделать наложение водяного знака в центр загружаемого фото? 
Размер загружаемого фото фиксированный - 240х320 .

Буду благодарен за любую полезную информацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за внимание)) 
Нашел решение:

```
    imagecopy($rfile, $rwatermark, imagesx($rfile) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($rfile) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($rwatermark), imagesy($rwatermark));
```

Comment: Из кода непонятно откуда взялись переменные `$sx`, `$marge_right`, `$sy` и `$marge_bottom`.  Так же не совсем понятно зачем вызывать `imagesx` и `imagesy`, если в первоначальном коде размеры изображений были уже определенны.